# Storage Spaces: Will removing a used USB 3.0 retain the data in a 2-way mirror setup?

Tags: filesystems, files, windows-8.1, storage-spaces

So I've just realized that the ReFS filesystem, although promising in a Storage Space solution, doesn't have certain NTFS features that I need. So I'm contemplating going back to NTFS.

Problem is that with removing a Storage Space, all the files within will be permanently deleted, according to Windows.

My setup currently houses **one internal hard-drive** and **one USB 3.0 hard-drive** in a **2-Way Mirror** Storage Space setup. So both hard-drives should technically have one copy each of every file, unless I misunderstand how Storage Spaces work.

My question is this:
**If I disconnect the USB 3.0 hard-drive, delete the Storage Space, and reconnect the hard-drive, will the files on the USB hard-drive still be accessible and usable?**

Comment: ReFS, also known as Killer FS.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the thing. If you're planning to change the file system anyway, you're going to have to backup your data at some point in this process regardless of whether your external drive is accessible after you disconnect it and delete the Storage Space. So, I think the smartest route is probably to back up your files, make the necessary configuration changes you need to make, then restore your files from your backup location.

But to answer your specific question, I think it's probable that the files themselves will be OK on the drive, and the PC will probably treat it as an external disk and mount it like any other. They'll just still be in ReFS.

But again, I'd back up to a different device before doing anything. Why risk your data?